# Misplaced DataGrid error indicator

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I was trying to use `DataGrid` to enable user to enter new records.
The `ItemsSource` is binding to `ObservableCollection<MyObject>`.
And `MyObject` implemented `IDataErrorInfo` for validation and `INotifyPropertyChanged` to Notify `PropertyChanged` to the UI.

**Question:**

How can I get over the following problem?

**Problem:**

In editing mode, when I typing in a long error string into a cell, it will show error indicator (red Border) around the `TextBox`, but when leaving the cell, the indicator will overrun to cover other columns like this:

[image: wrong validation width]

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,5"  CanUserAddRows="True"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  ItemsSource="{Binding Pricelist}" >
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Width="60" >
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">                            
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Price, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Price, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>                    
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**Note:**

I think all these are quite typical and should be straightforward, but my experience is that `DataGrid` is so cumbersome. Following are the steps I have done that gets me to this problem:

1. Removed the `ValidationErrorTemplate` for [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5099039/352101).
2. Explicitly defined `ElementStyle` and `EditingElementStyle` separately and set `Mode=TwoWay` in `ElementStyle` for [another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19663281/352101).
3. Removed `ValidatesOnDataErrors=True` from `ElementStyle` to allow user to be able to edit any other cells if there is error in the current cell.
4. Defined `MultiDataTrigger` to set the `BorderBrush` to `Red` if the cell's value is `Null` to show error indicators for empty cells.

I will probably use a `ItemsControl` instead, but I do like some of the build-in features of `DataGrid`.

Comment: It looks like this is a rant + 5 quasi questions. You've already asked one of the questions directly. Please break this down into individual questions with code samples for each.

Comment: @RQDQ, thanks but my question is about why `DataGrid` is so problematic in general. And I do have solutions for each of the problems I've pointed out.

Comment: @Bolu `Validation` is the only thing I've never liked from WPF. Forget it, it will only bring you headache. Personally, I've made my own validation framework based on attached properties and Validations at the ViewModel level, rather than at the Binding level, it works excellent and does not have any of the issues you're describing here.

Comment: @HighCore, I also do validations at the ViewModel level, but still using the default `ValidatingTemplate` in the View, which is the source of all these headaches I suppose?

Comment: @Bolu the whole thing is a general mess. it forces your `{Binding}`s to a much more verbose syntax, which pollutes your XAML unnecesarily. I would rather use an attached property to modify the visual appearance of the `CellTemplate` or something like that, and keep my Bindings to the default syntax of `{Binding MyProperty}`.

Comment: @HighCore, I can understand your approach in some way, are you able to share your attached property? Many thanks :P

Comment: @Bolu not really :P, it's part of my employer's intellectual property. I would share that, but don't have a choice.

Comment: @HighCore, thanks anyway for providing an alternative way of doing this.

Comment: Datagrid validation is a piece of crap in general. I use a dialog/entry point for new records and my datagrids display the set of good records entered from there.

Comment: @Shoe, interesting idea, web page like style.